# C# freeze ONLY mouse movement

Tags: c#, mouse

I am trying to disable just the mouse movement with C#, if is possible just the X or Y position.

I tried using

```
BlockInput(true);
```

But this will also freeze my keyboard.

Any help?

Comment: Um... Which part of .Net is `BlockInput`?

Comment: Blocking  mouse movement could not possibly be the best solution to whatever you're doing, unless the goal is to cause user frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to set the mouse sensitivity to 0, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Cursor.Clip` property to a rectangle to restrict cursor movement.

Comment: I don't want to freeze the mouse while i use my program, i want to freeze it while i'm in a other game

Comment: @Paul: I believe this would still work, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cursor.Clip.
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a nice article to handle keyboard and mouse.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

for mouse:

```
 actHook= new UserActivityHook(); // crate an instance
 actHook.OnMouseActivity+=new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoved);
```

and then in function do whatever you want:

```
public void MouseMoved(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    labelMousePosition.Text=String.Format("x={0}  y={1}", e.X, e.Y);
    if (e.Clicks>0) LogWrite("MouseButton     - " + e.Button.ToString());
}
```

Comment: And how should i freeze it?

Answer (score 0):

You could "simulate" blocked mouse.
When mouse position changes you return it to the original starting position you set up before. Use X and Y to set up starting mouse [position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like 960,540 (this is half of 1920,1080) and then you handle the mouse move event so that it returns cursor to the original position.

Comment: That won't be really freezed, it will only look like is trying to freeze it...and also C# isn't that fast..